# Is 'As per our discussion' and 'As per your instructions' wrong?

Tags: grammar

Is *As per our discussion, ...* and *As per your instructions, ...* wrong, and are they poor grammatical constructions?

*As per our conversation,* I will tender my resignation on Friday.

*Per our conversation,* I will tender my resignation on Friday.

Do I use *Per* or *As per* in these constructions, or is neither preferred? If neither, what are viable, concise substitutes?

Comment: Have you recently eaten a book of English idioms?  This is the third or fourth question of this type I've seen from you in the last few days!

Answer (score 12):

Either is acceptable usage in American English.

*As per* is a bit redundant, though.  It is essentially:  *As according to our conversation*.

So, feel free to use either construct.  But, *Per our conversation* is a bit more succinct with roughly equivalent meaning.

Comment: Proper grammar dictates the omission of redundancy. "As per" is not acceptable and is incorrect. Please use "Per...".